# java exception trace

Tags: java, exception

When i execute the below code,I am seeing the output as:

> Finally
>
> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at ClientTestConcepts.main(ClientTestConcepts.java:9)**

Who prints the bold faced statements.

```
public class ClientTestConcepts {
    public static void main(String []args){
        try{
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("Finally");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java runtime.

It catches all exceptions not handled in user code, and prints them on the error output (by default).

Comment: @JavaUser, whatever you do in the `catch` block :-) If you catch it within `main` and do not rethrow it, the runtime will not see it.

Answer (score 3):

Each thread has a default uncaught exception handler that runs when an exception makes it to the top of the stack.  The one you are observing is provided by [ThreadGroup.uncaughtException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable)):

> Called by the Java Virtual Machine when a thread in this thread group stops because of an uncaught exception, and the thread does not have a specific Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler  installed.
>
> The uncaughtException method of ThreadGroup does the following: (...)
>       ... a message containing the thread's name, as returned from the thread's getName method, and a stack backtrace, using the Throwable's printStackTrace method, is printed to the standard error stream.

If you want some other behaviour register an uncaught exception handler for the thread.

Comment: First of all, it's not the user that's using ThreadGroup.  Second of all, that's what's happening.  Whether it's obsolete or not (I would say it's not, since it's still very much used), it's what's causing the user behaviour now.  Not some magic in the Java runtime.

Comment: BTW if anybody knows how to fix that link, I'd be delighted.  It's interpreted correctly in the preview pane so I think it's a SO bug.

Comment: Well, the very quote says _"Called by the Java Virtual Machine"_ ... so it may not be magic, but it **is** caused by the Java runtime :-)

Comment: @Peter: Called, yes.  But it's not like it's printed in some native code.  It's fully Java code provided in the runtime library that actually does the printing.  And it's configurable.

Comment: I managed to fix the link by replacing the ' ' (space) in it with `%20` :-)

Comment: I don't think _Java runtime_ is supposed to mean _native code_ (but I may be wrong of course). And your info about its configurability is useful, +1 for you :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Peter!  I'll keep that in mind for future reference.  Interesting that it didn't escape it for me, given that I used the editor button to insert the link in the first place.

Comment: @Peter, I of course agree about the Java runtime, though clearly anything that happens at runtime not by user code is happening because of the Java runtime.  So I was trying to be a bit more explicit.

Comment: Yeah, the editor is not very good regarding unusual links (containing spaces or brackets, among others). But also it is the cleverness of modern browsers. They used to show the links with the escape characters included, but now that I checked it, Firefox at least shows the space.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks, that's the reason it happened.  I found a better way to copy a link from Vimperator.